# Can't mock a property of an aliased class in Mockery

Tags: php, mockery

I'm trying to test some code that calls the [Google Drive API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). Here's the code under test:

```
class GDrive {
    ...
    public function __construct(\Google_Client $client = null) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client);

    $root = $service->files->get($this->root, [
        "supportsAllDrives" => true
    ]);
    ...
}
```

`$this->client` is a mock of `\Google_Client`.

Here's the test:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(Google_Client::class);
$this->gDrive = new GDrive($mock);

$gDriveMock = m::mock('overload:\Google_Service_Drive');
$gDriveFilesMock = m::mock('\Google\Service\Drive\Resource\Files');
$gDriveMock->files = $gDriveFilesMock;
```

I'm trying to mock out the call to `$service->files->get`, but when the `$root = $service->files->get` line is executed in `GDrive` I get:

```
Undefined property: Google_Service_Drive::$files
```

If I don't (attempt to) mock the classes out then the code works ok.

I guess there's a problem with either (or both):

- My use of `overload` to mock the directly instantiated `Google_Service_Drive`
- The `->` syntax for setting a property on the mock

I've tried not using aliases in the references to the Google Drive API, but it doesn't appear to help.